# CSS Change text colour on WooCommerce variation drop down WP theme is overriding

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce, themes

Straight forward issue, I have Zerif Pro for WP and it has a lovely section to customise text colour. However, that appears to be overriding certain areas which I would like to be a different colour.

The issue I am having is with this page http://www.chaotopia.com/product/aromatics-zodiac-incenses/ (included the page not the css as unsure which part is affected)

As you can see, the drop down list appears blank because the text is white on white. I had a similar issue on the product quantities but managed to find that and resolve it by adding black as a custom colour within the main style sheet.

Unfortunately, I cannot find where to add a custom colour for the variation drop downs and make the text black so it can be seen. I intend to use variation on multiple products so ideal would like any lists to globally have black text.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.   Although you have provided a [**link to an example or site**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it), if the link were to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem.

Comment: Agree totally but in this case, don't know which code to include from all the style sheets etc so can't but will update when answered. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On line 338 of the HTML source you have a `<style>` block that includes the rule `..., select, ... { color: #ffffff; }`

This is what is making the text inside the `<select>` element white, but it is also the rule that sets the text color for a number of other elements. So it will not suffice to simply change this to `color: #000000;` - this would affect many other elements as well.

Instead, you need to override this rule for only `<select>` elements. One way to do this is to add `select{ color: #000000; }` in a CSS stylesheet that is loaded *after* line 338, thus overriding the first rule. Another way is to add `select { color: #000000 !important; }` in any CSS stylesheet. I would recommend the former, because the `!important` rule could lead to further confusion down the line.